# Problem with Frameworks in Command Line Tool

Tags: swift, macos, frameworks, command-line-tool, xcode10.1

Before everyone starts throwing other stack-overflow and forum posts at me: I looked at them all. None of them are helping.

I have a simple cmd tool called `swizzler` and want to embed the `SwizzleSrc` framework in it. I have followed all the tutorials and stack overflows with no luck. Here is what I am getting.

**Build**

```
2019-02-07 19:22:46.785680-0500 Terminal[67444:11837029] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
2019-02-07 19:22:46.786939-0500 Terminal[67444:11837029] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
```

**Run**

```
Last login: Thu Feb  7 19:21:08 on ttys018
NAME-iMac:~ NAME$ /Users/NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swizzler-aslysekmorknabdslxbxfaeuiztk/Build/Products/Debug/swizzler ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SwizzleSrc.framework/Versions/A/SwizzleSrc
  Referenced from: /Users/NAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/swizzler-aslysekmorknabdslxbxfaeuiztk/Build/Products/Debug/swizzler
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Can someone please help? I have been trying for days with no avail.

Comment: Have you found a fix for this issue yet? Thanks!

Comment: Not yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

To fix your issue we need to change how Xcode handles Swift *Command Line Tool* targets by default, specifically the linking convention against the Swift standard libraries.

We need to:

- embed the Swift standard libraries in your `SwizzleSrc` framework
- force your `swizzler` command line executable to dynamically link all Swift libraries
- finally, make sure your `swizzler` executable is then able to find all needed Swift libraries (now placed in the framework target)

Let's get started (assumes you are using **Xcode 10.1** or above):

### Embedding the Swift Libraries in the Framework

This is pretty straightforward. Change the following **Build Settings** for the `SwizzleSrc` framework target:

- **Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries** to **Yes**

### Dynamically Linking all Swift Libraries in the Command Line Tool

This is the somewhat tricky part. Add the following **User-Defined** settings for the `swizzler` tool target (in the **Build Settings**):

- `SWIFT_FORCE_DYNAMIC_LINK_STDLIB` set to `YES`
- `SWIFT_FORCE_STATIC_LINK_STDLIB` set to `NO`

(To add a new **User-Defined** setting just click the `+` button just below the **Build Settings** tab title.)

This will ensure your command line executable will *dynamically* link all Swift libraries instead (i.e., by default they are *statically* linked). By the way, these exact same settings are used by the Swift Package Manager to fix a related issue.

### Update the Runpath for the Command Line Tool

Add the following **Runpath Search Path** entries for the `swizzler` tool target (in the **Build Settings**):

- `@executable_path`
- `@executable_path/SwizzleSrc.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks`

Now clean your build folder, rebuild again *both* targets, and check if this fixed your issue for good ;)

### References

For further information, be sure to check the following links as well:

- [How to add a dynamic Swift framework to a Command Line Tool](https://medium.com/livefront/how-to-add-a-dynamic-swift-framework-to-a-command-line-tool-bab6426d6c31)
- [Embedded Swift Frameworks on Command Line Tools](http://colemancda.github.io/2015/02/12/embedded-swift-frameworks-osx-command-line-tools)
- [macOS Command Line Tool with Swift Cocoa Framework: Library not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39086761/819340)

I also created a (very!) simple Xcode project demonstrating the steps above:

- [github.com/pmattos/Swift-CLI-with-Framework](https://github.com/pmattos/Swift-CLI-with-Framework)

Comment: I tested all steps above on a clean Xcode project (containing only those 2 targets) and it worked just fine. BTW, I was getting the same error as you before. Anyway, I will try to upload my project to GitHub later today...

Comment: Hey @ImportAccelerate, I uploaded a simple Xcode project following the steps outlined in my answer: https://github.com/pmattos/Swift-CLI-with-Framework